# Mongo Query question $gt,$lt

Tags: mongodb

I have a query below. I want get items between 4 and 6 so only a:1 should match because it has the value 5 in b.

```
> db.test.find({ b : { $gt :  4  }, b: {$lt : 6}});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d54cff54364000000004331"), "a" : 1, "b" : [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d54d0074364000000004332"), "a" : 2, "b" : [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ] }
>
```

Can someone tell be why a:2 is matching this query? I can't really see why it is being returned.

I also tried what was specified in the tutorial but id did not seem to work:

```
> db.test.find({ b : { $gt :  4, $lt : 6}});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d54cff54364000000004331"), "a" : 1, "b" : [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d54d0074364000000004332"), "a" : 2, "b" : [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ] }
>
```

And this one to avoid any confusion regarding GT/GTE

```
> db.test.find({b: {$gt: 4.5, $lt: 5.5}});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d54cff54364000000004331"), "a" : 1, "b" : [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d54d0074364000000004332"), "a" : 2, "b" : [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ] }
>
```

only a:1 should be returned.

As suggested, I gave $elemMatch a try but it did not appear to work either (objectIds are different because I am on a different machine)

```
> db.test.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d5a24a5e82e00000000433f"), "a" : 1, "b" : [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d5a24bbe82e000000004340"), "a" : 2, "b" : [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ] }
> db.test.find({b: {$elemMatch: {$gt : 4, $lt: 6 }}});
>
```

No documents were returned.

Comment: Actually, both documents should be returned, the question means "give me all documents where `b` has a value that is between 4 and 6", and this is satisfied by both documents. Could you explain in more detail what it is want to query for? Why should the first document be found but not the second?

Comment: As you say above, I want all documents which have a b between 4 and 6. Only a:1 satisfies this (not both) because a:2 does not contain any values between 4 and 6  (using gt and lt exclude 4 and 6 themselves where as gte and lte would include them). I tried a different query (see edited question) which is more clear and it still doesn't function correctly...

Comment: I see what you mean now, I thought about it as a range (and ranges are usually include the first element), but of course it's not, it's a strict less than and greater than. I've deleted my answer since it's now clear that it was wrong.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This is a really confusing topic. I work at 10gen and I had to spend a while wrapping my head around it ;)

Let's walk through how the query engine processes this query.

Here's the query again:

```
> db.test.find({ b : { $gt :  4, $lt : 6}});
```

When it gets to the record that seems like it shouldn't match...

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d54cff54364000000004331"), "a" : 1, "b" : [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ] }
```

The match is not performed against each element of the array, but rather against the array as a whole.

The comparison is performed in three steps:

**Step 1**: Find all documents where b has a value greater than 4

b: [2,4,6,8] matches because 6 & 8 are greater than 4

**Step 2**: Find all documents where b has a value less than 6

b: [2,4,6,8] matches because 2 & 4 are less than 6

**Step 3**: Find the set of documents that matched in both step 1 & 2.

The document with b: [2,4,6,8] matched both steps 1 & 2 so it is returned as a match. Note that results are also de-duplicated in this step, so the same document won't be returned twice.

If you want your query to apply to the individual elements of the array, rather than the array as a whole, you can use the $elemMatch operator. For example

```
> db.temp.find({b: {$elemMatch: {$gt: 4, $lt: 5}}})
> db.temp.find({b: {$elemMatch: {$gte: 4, $lt: 5}}})
  { "_id" : ObjectId("4d558b6f4f0b1e2141b66660"), "b" : [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] }
```

Comment: Thanks, Jared, for the well layed out answer. However, upon trying it, it does not seem to work. (I tried "db.test.find({b: {$elemMatch: {$gt : 4, $lt: 6 }}});" as you described. (please see edited question for details) Can you shed any light on this?

Comment: Strange. It works for me. 

> db.array2.save({b:[2,3,4,5]})
> db.array2.save({b:[2,4,6,8]})
> db.array2.find({b: {$elemMatch: {$gt: 4, $lt: 6}}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d5a9268ec5855af36625ed6"), "b" : [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ] }
> 

What version of MongoDB are you using? $elemMatch was added 1.3.1, so if you're still using 1.2 it won't work.

Comment: Doesn't work here. Just copied and pasted your queries (insert and then query). I have 1.6.5. It looks like it might be a bug: http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1264

Comment: Ah. Yes you are correct. I was running tests in 1.7.5. When I run in 1.6.5 it does not work. it seems that this will not be backported. the good news is that 1.8 is coming out very soon and will include this fix.

Comment: I had to lookup what 10gen is :D

Answer (score 10):

$gt

```
Syntax: {field: {$gt: value} }
```

eg:

```
db.inventory.find( { qty: { $gt: 20 } } )
```

$lt

```
Syntax: {field: {$lt: value} }
```

eg:

```
db.inventory.find( { qty: { $lt: 20 } } )
```

eg2:

```
db.inventory.find({ qty : { $gt :  20, $lt : 60}});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.find( {$and:[ {b:{$gt:4}}, {b:{$lt:6}} ]} )
```

Comment: No. The syntax as show in the accepted answer is correct and is already an "and" operation. This is terse and a bad example of readable syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the detailed document for the understanding,

```
db.test.insertMany([
    {"_id":1, "x":11, "a":1, "b":[1]},
    {"_id":2, "x":15, "a":4, "b":[1,2,3]},
    {"_id":3, "x":19, "a":5, "b":[1,2,3,4,5]},
    {"_id":4, "x":13, "a":6, "b":[6,8,10]},
    {"_id":5, "x":16, "a":13, "b":[11]},
    {"_id":6, "x":18, "a":11, "b":[5]},
    {"_id":7, "x":15, "a":15, "b":[3,5,7]},
    {"_id":8, "x":12, "a":18, "b":[3,7,9]},
    {"_id":9, "x":14, "a":21, "b":[4,6]}
]);
```

Below queries are included to make idea clear about comparision,
Query-1: `db.test.find({b: {$lt: 6}}); //(any element of b) < 6`

```
{ "_id" : 1, "x" : 11, "a" : 1, "b" : [ 1 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "x" : 15, "a" : 4, "b" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "x" : 19, "a" : 5, "b" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "x" : 18, "a" : 11, "b" : [ 5 ] }
{ "_id" : 7, "x" : 15, "a" : 15, "b" : [ 3, 5, 7 ] }
{ "_id" : 8, "x" : 12, "a" : 18, "b" : [ 3, 7, 9 ] }
{ "_id" : 9, "x" : 14, "a" : 21, "b" : [ 4, 6 ] }
```

`

Query-2: `db.test.find({b: {$gt: 4}, b:{$lt : 6}});// it is translated to db.test.find({b:{$lt : 6}}); hence the outcome of Query-1 and Query-2 is the same.`

```
{ "_id" : 1, "x" : 11, "a" : 1, "b" : [ 1 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "x" : 15, "a" : 4, "b" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "x" : 19, "a" : 5, "b" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "x" : 18, "a" : 11, "b" : [ 5 ] }
{ "_id" : 7, "x" : 15, "a" : 15, "b" : [ 3, 5, 7 ] }
{ "_id" : 8, "x" : 12, "a" : 18, "b" : [ 3, 7, 9 ] }
{ "_id" : 9, "x" : 14, "a" : 21, "b" : [ 4, 6 ] }
```

Query-3: `db.test.find({b: {$gt: 4, $lt: 6}});`

```
{ "_id" : 3, "a" : 5, "b" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] }//(element 5) > 4 and (element 5) < 6` => The matching element is same here element 5
{ "_id" : 6, "a" : 11, "b" : [ 5 ] }//(element 5) > 4 and (element 5) < 6 => The matching element is same here element 5
{ "_id" : 7, "a" : 15, "b" : [ 3, 5, 7 ] }//(element 5) > 4 and (element 5) < 6 => The matching element is same here element 5
{ "_id" : 8, "a" : 18, "b" : [ 3, 7, 9 ] }//(element 5) > 7 and (element 3) < 6 => The matching elements are different i.e. here element 5 and element 3
{ "_id" : 9, "a" : 21, "b" : [ 4, 6 ] }//(element 6) > 4 and (element 4) < 6 => The matching elements are different i.e. here element 4 and element 6
```

Query-4: `db.test.find({b: {$elemMatch: {$gt : 4, $lt: 6 }}});`

```
{ "_id" : 3, "a" : 5, "b" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] }//(element 5) > 4 and (element 5) <6
{ "_id" : 6, "a" : 11, "b" : [ 5 ] }//(element 5) > 4 and (element 5) <6
{ "_id" : 7, "a" : 15, "b" : [ 3, 5, 7 ] }//(element 5) > 4 and (element 5) <6
```

**Query-3 and Query-4 are interesting to know about.**
Query-3: List document having array b element x>4 and element y<6. The elements x and y may be the same or the different.
Query-4: List document having array b element x>4 and element y<6. The elements x and y must be the same.