# MongoDB query ignored when querying more than one value

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a document structure that contains, amongst other keys, a simple integer array and another number key, similar to:

```
{
    otherKey: "1234"
    numArray: [3200, 3220, 3230, 5433],
    empBand: 4
}
```

I want to query the base so I get documents where the numArray contains any value that falls between 3200 and 3220 AND the empBand is equal to 4.

The query I am using is:

```
db.Data.find({ numArray: { $gte : 3200, $lte: 3220 }, empBand : 4})
```

However this query completely ignores the numArray criteria and brings me back random documents where the empBand is equal to 4.

If I run the following though:

```
db.Data.find({numarray: { $gte : 3200, $lte: 3220 }})
```

I get the correct results, i.e. only documents which contain a value in the array (any value) which falls between 3200 and 3220.

I have indexes set up for both values for other queries and using explain() I can see that the index being used for query just running on numArray is the numArray_empBand_otherKey index.

Using explain() on the initial query tells me that the index being used is an empData_otherKey index, not the expected numArray_empBand index, as if the first criteria is being completely ignored.

I've tried writing the query using $and as such:

```
db.Data.find({$and: [ { numArray: { $gte: 3200, $lte: 3220 } }, { empBand: 4}])
```

and I still get the wrong results.

Hinting with the numArray led index still gets the wrong results.

Am I missing something completely obvious?

Edit:

These are results I get with the second query:

```
{ "numArray" : [ 3210, 46380, 47230 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210, 3220 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3110, 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
{ "numArray" : [ 3210 ] }
```

Here are some results from the first query:

```
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 21250, 2522, 7487 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 1110, 45112 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 1130, 10390 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 1470, 46330 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 17510, 1753 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 1490, 93199 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 1500, 49410, 77390 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 1190, 43390 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 15310, 1533 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 1250, 1290, 10390, 46310 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 1610, 43999 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 3110, 47230 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 1621, 47799 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 1130, 16290, 38320, 91030 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 28520, 2875 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 1130, 47789 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 28520, 2875, 3663 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 27510, 2754, 2912 ] }
{ "empBand" : 4, "numArray" : [ 1190, 1290, 1630, 46220 ] }
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the results you are getting that you consider wrong? Please edit your question to include these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post had the answer:

[Mongo Query question $gt,$lt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966203/mongo-query-question-gt-lt)

I need to use elemMatch :

```
db.Data.find({ numArray: { $elemMatch: { $gte: 3200, $lte: 3220 }}, empBand : 4})
```

Which gets the correct results.

Comment: And right you are. I just went through a useless exercise unwinding in aggregation to come to the same conclusion. Question is, do you **get** the reason **why** the *range* would fail without the `$elemMatch` constraint?

Comment: After reading the linked post it makes sense that the constraints are applied separately to elements in the array, so at least one element in the array matches $gte and at least one matches $lte.

Comment: Okay. Didn't read that one myself, but it seems you have the basic "scan forwards & scan backwards" understanding. `$elemMatch` reduces that to the set that is **actually** matching in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty you've hit a bug, more specifically [SERVER-1937: $gt/$lt/$ne with scalar operand yields inconsistent matches on arrays](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1937)